# Azure Artifact feed causing 'incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache' whenever an operation is run

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yarnpkg, azure-artifacts

As a bypass I'm currently running `yarn cache clean` every time, but this is takes time + is a bit tedious to have to do before each operation.

I'm using an .npmrc file to point towards an azure devops artifact feed which has npm itself as an upstream.

This happens every single time across multiple projects configured the same way.

EDIT: nevermind, this seems to be an issue with the latest version of YARN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Azure Artifact feed causing 'incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache' whenever an operation is run

Indeed, this is the issue for the latest version of YARN (`1.19.0`).

The workaround for this issue is exactly what you are using now:

```
yarn cache clean
yarn add --dev jest
```

Check the document [yarn cache](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/cache/):

[image]

If you do not want to clean the cache before each operation, you can try to downgrading yarn version on the server:

```
yarn policies set-version 1.18
```

The issue tracking ticket:

[Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7584)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It's good to get confirmation that other people are experiencing this. I'll downgrade to 1.18.